# How to securely store and pass password for third party service between services?

Tags: python, microservices, soa

We are working at app which manage user documents.
One new feature we are implementing - working with user's emails.

User input in `settings` tab his credentials (login, password, imapProvider). Then we pass this data to another our service which is responsible for retrieving emails.

**Problems**

- We can't store and pass plain password

There must be mechanism which will encrypt password on one side and decrypt on another side. Any ideas how to implement it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should check if the supported third party services have APIs that issue tokens such as OAuth2, etc. I wouldn't ask users for their passwords especially to email since email is used as a sort of identity confirmation for a lot of accounts. Also, I wouldn't give my credentials to any other service.

Comment: There are plenty shared secret solutions out there, my advice is to go with one of those. Hashicorp's vault seems to be very popular but a little search shows quite a few of them.

Comment: @DillanWilding problem is that there can be really a lot of mail services...

Comment: @Grzegorzg Everyone here says use something other than passwords (OAuth2, RSA, etc.) because there is no "pass through" password security in which it can be cryptographically secure and also allow you to use the password for traditional user authentication for email services. If you can use the original password to log in someone can get it. I haven't checked the market share of email service providers lately but I bet if you implemented 2-3 you'd get the majority of people, not to mention if you implement OAuth2 or RSA for Gmail, anyone can make an account for free.

Answer (score 1):

You could have your email service to generate a [RSA public/private](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_algorithm) key pair. The email service would be the only one aware of the private key (used for deciphering), but would share with other services the public key (used for encrypting). Email login data should be stored encrypted, and ideally not on the email service (if the email service is compromised, the email login data from your users won't be as well). Encryption using the public key can even be done in the front end using javascript.

But be aware that it is strongly discouraged to implement your own cryptographic stack, as there are thousands of ways to have it wrong. Unless you are an expert in cryptography, use trusted libraries.